# Como cambiar Valores enteros a decimales en Chart JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Estoy trabajando con Chart JS (https://www.chartjs.org) y un plugin del mismo que se llama datalabels para mostrar los valores en el gráfico.

Uso una gráfica Radar donde muestro una calificación por servicio del 1 al 5

Necesito que los valores se muestren exactos 4,1 4,8 4,3 de esta forma, actualmente solo me muestra el numero completo 4,4,4,4 de esta forma.

Dejo mi script por si alguno sabe cómo puedo lograr mostrarlo en decimales.

```js
var Etiqueta4 = <%= Etiquetas4 %>;
                    var Valor4 = <%= valores4 %>;
                    var ctx2 = document.getElementById("Graf0").getContext('2d');
                    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily  = "candara"  
                    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize  = 0  
                    var Graf0 = new Chart(ctx2, {
                        type: 'radar',
                        responsive: true,
                        scaleSteps: 4,
                        scaleStepWidth: 5,
                        scaleStartValue: 1,
                        data: {
                            labels: Etiqueta4,
                            datasets: [{
                                backgroundColor: ['rgba(232,95,0,0.4)'],
                                scaleSteps: 5,
                                fill: true,
                                min: 1,
                                max: 5,
                                scaleStartValue: 1,
                                pointRadius: 3,
                                pointBorderWidth: 3,
                                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                                pointBackgroundColor: "#FF4400",
                                pointBorderColor: ['rgba(255,68,0,0.9)'],
                                data: Valor4,},
                            ]
                        },

                        options: {
                            plugins: {
                                datalabels:{
                                    color: '#000',

                                    font: {
                                        size: 20,
                                        weight: 'bold'
                                    }
                                }
                            },

                            legend: { 
                                display: false 
                            },

                            scale: {
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    min: 0.5,
                                    max: 5,
                                    stepSize: 0.5,   
                                    fontSize: 22

                                },

                                pointLabels: {
                                    fontSize: 27,
                                    fontColor: '#000'
                                },
                            },
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'ENCUESTA - EVALUACIÓN DE DESEMPEÑO',
                                fontSize: 30,
                                fontFamily: "candara",
                                fontColor: '#000'
                            },
                        }                       
                    });
```

```html
<div class="grafico_radar">
                    <canvas id="Graf0" class="radar"></canvas>
                </div>
```

```html
 Private Sub buscar_evaluacion()
        Try
            Dim sResp = oDatos.Get_Encuesta
            Valores4.Append("[")
            Etiquetas4.Append("[")
            For Each row As DataRow In sResp.Tables(0).Rows
                Valores4.Append(String.Format("'{0}',", Val(row("Valor").ToString())))
                Etiquetas4.Append(String.Format("'{0}',", row("Titulo").ToString()))
            Next
            Etiquetas4.Append("]")
            Valores4.Append("]")
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, una pregunta ¿Qué datos tiene tu array de datos (`valores4`)?. Porque tal como tienes configurado el chart debería mostrarte los puntos con los decimales.

Comment: Valores4 envia 5 Valores del 1 al 5 amplio mi pregunta con el back end

Comment: Pues en tu backend veo que estás almacenando un tipo `string`. Corrígeme si me equivoco, pero `valores4` tal como lo construyes no es un array con números, en cambio es un `string`.

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un `console.log(typeof Valor4)` y además un `console.log(Valor4)`, después que lo asignas para saber que te devuelve?. Me refiero a hacerlo en el FrontEnd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se puede encontrar en 2 casos.
1. El campo valor de tu for each --> Val(row("Valor").ToString() te esta regresando un valor entero, prueba con capturar el dato en una variable tipo string y luego agregas al variable al código:
Ejemplo:

```
   Private Sub buscar_evaluacion()
        Try
            Dim sResp = oDatos.Get_Encuesta
            Dim dato As String
            Valores4.Append("[")
            Etiquetas4.Append("[")
            For Each row As DataRow In sResp.Tables(0).Rows
                dato = row("Valor").ToString()
                Valores4.Append(String.Format("'{0}',", dato))
                Etiquetas4.Append(String.Format("'{0}',", row("Titulo").ToString()))
            Next
            Etiquetas4.Append("]")
            Valores4.Append("]")
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

2. Revisa que la configuración regional del IIS comulgue con la configuración regional de SQL, el cual te trae el dato.
   Si SQL te retorna valor decimal con coma (,) tu servidor IIS debe estar configurado con separador decimal coma (,)

Con una de éstas 2 opciones (o ambas) te debe funcionar.

Comment: Use ambos metodos y funcionaron correctamente. Gracias